# Switch to hg-flow model: how to rebase commits and branches

Tags: git, mercurial, workflow, branch, rebase

I started some time ago a small project and used mercurial as RCS.
All commits were done in the `default` branch, except for one feature branch currently in development in a separate clone of the project.
The project became quite important and I'd like to switch to [Driessen's model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

I've been able to rebase all commits from `default:rev1` to `develop` using

```
$ # Starting in the default branch
$ hg up -r 0
$ hg branch develop
$ hg ci -m 'created the develop branch'
$ hg rebase --source 1
```

My problem is that I can't import my `feature/new-feature` branch into the `develop` branch without losing the branch information.
I'm quite confident there is a adequat way to do it but I can't find it.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this is the workaround I came to.
Maybe there is a proper solution.
Anyway, this works.

```
$ # Create branch develop at rev 0.
$ hg up -r 0
$ hg branch develop
$ hg ci -m 'creating branch develop'
$ 
$ # Rebase all commits into the develop branch.
$ # This will merge the feature/new-feature branch into develop.
$ hg rebase -s 1
$ 
$ # Re-create the feature/new-feature branch from its original parent.
$ hg up -r 357
$ hg branch feature/new-feature
$ hg ci -m 'created branch feature/new-feature'
$ 
$ # Move commits that belong to this branch from develop from newly re-created
$ # branch.
$ hg rebase --base 358 --dest tip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try hgflow. It's like git-flow for Mercurial
https://bitbucket.org/yinwm/hgflow/wiki/UserManual

Comment: I's good to use the hgflow plugin, but that documentation doesn't address the main question about losing branch information when you rebase a feature branch onto `develop`.  In my experience, the "flow: Created branch"  changeset (created by hg flow) disappears, and the other changesets from the feature branch think that they are on `develop` after the rebase.  This seems like a bug.